# How to fix input with Parse.Console.ReadLine();?

Tags: c#, input, struct

```
struct Snaga 
{
    public int Napad;
    public int Odbrana;
    public int FizickaSprema;
    public int Kontola;
    public int Psiha;
}

Snaga.Napad = Console.ReadLine();
```

This dont work.

How to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you want it to do that it dont do?

Answer (score 1):

That property is an int, you need to convert it.

```
snaga.Napad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dBErGg

Comment: Please put the code for the answer in the answer itself. A link to an offsite demo is great, but the code should be visible right here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GlX0fr
This is code.
I want to input Napad,Odbrana,FizickaSprema,Kontrola and Psiha.
Than share it with 5 and Snaga will be all that /5 ... if u understand me